# Odoo 9.0c: how to get the name of the current usser in sale order report qweb?

Tags: report, odoo-9, qweb

could you guy please help me to point out the right methods to show the current user (the one who direct ly print the report, not the one who created the report) on the duplicate qweb report? Moreover, my purpose is set the name under QR code form. this is my code:

```
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('QR', o.name, 80, 80)" style="width:80px;height:80px;"/>
                                                    <img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('QR', o.user.name, 80, 80)" style="width:80px;height:80px;"/>
                                                </div>
```

then i get this erorr :

```
QWebException: "'sale.order' object has no attribute 'user'" while evaluating
"'/report/barcode/?type=%s&value=%s&width=%s&height=%s' % ('QR', o.user.name, 80, 80)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access current user form qweb report using **user** ie,

```
<span t-esc="user.name"></span>
```

current partner as

```
<span t-esc="user.partner_id.name"></span>
```

Have a look at odoo 9 report [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/reports.html)

Comment: Thank for replying back, actually i have tried to get the current user name under QR code form, and when access the "user.name" the system return back an error. update the question you can see my code and following by the erorr.

Comment: @tuấnanhphạm object is an instance od sale.order, you need to use exact code in my user.

Comment: oh, thanks for sharing your knowledge, let me try it first then i will return a feedback. have a nice day, friend.